# for some, but not all, form submission got "Could not determine access type for property "id"."

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

I have a complex form that maps to a collection of `Entity`, that permits to buy ticket at a given pricing for an event, for most of the events it works, but for one of them, we got in a repeatable fashion the error `Could not determine access type for property "id"`

In such a case I know that `Could not determine access type for property X` is because a setter is missing. There's indeed no `setId()` method and `id` is `protected`, but I think symfony should not try to set the id in the first place (because it works for the other forms, i.e the tickets are bought, and appears correctly link to the event etc.)

So my question is **why in some case symfony REQUIRES the setId()**

I have the following entities

```
class OrderFront
{
    use Traits\HasId;
    /**
     * List of pricings set on this event
     *
     * @Assert\Valid()
     * @ORM\OneToMany(  
     *     targetEntity="QuantityByPricing",
     *     mappedBy="orderFront",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    private $quantitiesByPricing;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    public $occurenceId;

    public function getQuantitiesByPricing(): Collection
    {
        return $this->quantitiesByPricing;
    }

    public function addQuantitiesByPricing(QuantityByPricing $quantityByPricing)
    {
        $quantityByPricing->setOrderFront($this);
        $this->quantitiesByPricing[] = $quantityByPricing;
        return $this;
    }

}

class QuantityByPricing
{
    use Traits\HasId;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $quantity = 0;

    /**
     * The pricing of this ticket
     *
     * @var Pricing
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pricing")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
     *     name="pricing_id",
     *     nullable=false,
     *     referencedColumnName="id"
     * )
     */
    public $pricing;
}
```

Indeed the trait "HasId" has no setter (but it's on purpose) or at least until now it has never been a problem

```
trait HasId
{
    /** 
     *
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="guid") }
     * @ORM\Id
     *
     * @Assert\Uuid()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return guid
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

And the forms

```
    class OrderType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {   
            $builder
                ->add(
                    'quantitiesByPricing',
                    CollectionType::class,
                    ['entry_type' => QuantityByPricingType::class]
                )
                ->add('occurenceId', HiddenType::class)
           ;
        }
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {   
            $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\OrderFront']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * sub-form to buy X tickets of a given pricing
     */
    class QuantityByPricingType extends AbstractType
    {   
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('quantity')
                ->add('pricing',HiddenPricingType::class)
            ;
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\QuantityByPricing']);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    class HiddenPricingType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {   
            $builder->add('id', HiddenType::class);
        }

        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Pricing']);
        }
    }

class Pricing
{
    use Traits\HasId;
}
```

The controller creating the form looks like this

```
      // call the DB to set the possible pricings
      // inside it calls addQuantityByPricing
      $orderFront = $this->_createOrderFront(); 
      $form = $this->createForm(OrderType::class, $orderFront);
      $form->handleRequest($request);
```

The exception traceback is the following

```
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException:
Could not determine access type for property "id".

  at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:652
  at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->writeProperty(array(object(Pricing), object(Pricing)), 'id', '80424145-ca68-4dce-b4f0-644a423d3aad')
```

And when adding some `debug` I can see that the 2 `Pricing` are

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Pricing {#1375 ▶}   # id  "d82cafb8-432b-4e20-ac9f-66e48dc55458"
  1 => & Pricing {#1375 ▶} # id  "d82cafb8-432b-4e20-ac9f-66e48dc55458"
]
```

So it seems that symfony is trying to override the id of this pricing (which is a valid/existing one) by an other valid/existing one, which is I think the reason why it try to "replace" it, by trying to call the setter and fails, but why does it do so ?

Edit:

After some more debugging I found a troubling coincidence:

- `d82cafb8-432b-4e20-ac9f-66e48dc55458` is the first id to add when i added some debug in the `addQuantitiesByPricing` method
- `80424145-ca68-4dce-b4f0-644a423d3aad` is the pricing id with the index 0 in the submitted form

Edit2: the way my controller create the form (and which is the one calling the `addQuantitiesByPricing` making `d82cafb8-432b-4e20-ac9f-66e48dc55458` to appear first ), make that we first retrieve these Ids from the database BEFORE taking the Ids POSTed

Comment: Your  `HiddenPricingType` you define a hidden id. How does your entity looks like?

Comment: @Stony I edited a bit the question, the formatting made it not clear that HideenPricingType is mapped to the entity Pricing

Comment: I suppose you temporarily add a setId just to confirm what the form package is trying to do.  Might give a clue.  The form collections are somewhat dependent on the order of the items so maybe something is fooling with them.

Comment: @Cerad adding a setId at least make the exception disapear, I haven't checked it didn't create any side except, in the meantime I've edited the question to add some information, because as you said, something troubling is going on with the order

Comment: @Cerad I've edited again, your comment has made me focus on the way the order is decided ,  and it is true in the html, the index in the form is decided because I make a "sort" based on the date of the event , while in the controller , before creating the form, I take the id from the database, so maybe the order database/html used to be the same and this one is the first to have a different order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the order in which the elements were added using `addQuantitiesByPricing` when creating the main entity of the form (i.e `OrderFront` ) was not the same in which they were added in the HTML (there was a `sort` hidden in the twig file )

So the POSTed array of `QuantityByPricing` was not in the same order as the array of `QuantityByPricing` created by the database, so when Symfony was doing its magic to see which field needed to be updated, it saw that the first element of my array had a different `id` than the first element of the POSTed  array, and then tried to replace it by searching first its setter so `setId()` hence the exception

The reason why I didn't see this bug before was because for some (un)lucky reason the array coming from the database was already sorted, so the twig sort was doing nothing

Note: not related directly to this specific context, but if the size of the posted array is less than the size of the database array you will get the same stacktrace (except the last argument will be `null` )

```
Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\Exception\NoSuchPropertyException:
Could not determine access type for property "id".

  at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php:652
  at Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor->writeProperty(array(object(Pricing), object(Pricing)), 'id', null)
```

note2: an other solution that could had work would have been to reorder the array before submiting it using the `PRE_SUBMIT` event in my `OrderType`

```
        ->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $submittedData = $event->getData();
                if (!array_key_exists('quantitiesByPricing', $submittedData)) {
                    return;
                }
                $form = $event->getForm();
                dump($submittedData['quantitiesByPricing']);

                //Re-index the array to ensure the forms
                // stay in the submitted order.
                $submittedData['quantitiesByPricing'] = /* some code to reorder the submitted form in the same order as the data from the database */

                $event->setData($submittedData);
            }
        )
```